# Count for all combinations of two other columns on a large scale

Tags: sql, count, scalable, timesten

**SETUP** - 
I have a large but simple query that usually takes a second or two to run

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.Col_1, t1.Col_2, t1.Col_3, Col_4, ... t2.Col_3, t3.Col_2, ...
    (14 columns total)
FROM Table_1 t1 INNER JOIN Table_2 t2 ON (t1.COL_3 = t2.COL_1) ... 
    (4 joins total, each on a different column in Table_1)
```

Table_1 is the primary table, and its Col_1 is the primay key for the entire database (all other tables just have a foreign key off a column in Table_1.)

**PROBLEM** - 
I need to find the largest possible count if I WHERE only on t1.Col_2 and t1.Col_4. As in, for existing combination of values in column 2 and column 4 of table 1, what is the largest result set I would get if I selected based on any of those combinations? For scale, there are over 200,000 unique combinations of the two columns.

I tried to avoid the problem by collecting all combinations of COL_2 and COL_4 and then query for counts using those combinations, but it took 30 minutes to test ~2,500. That's too slow.

What I'm NOT trying to answer:

- How many unique combinations of Col_2 and Col_4 exist. [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23247574/sql-count-how-can-i-count-how-many-distinct-values-are-in-a-table-when-an-other?rq=1) and [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31973002/sql-return-all-combinations-of-two-columns-and-their-number-of-occurences)
- a small-scale version of the same problem. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24240421/determining-count-of-unique-combination-of-two-fields-in-mysql) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156717/sql-count-distinct-values-from-one-column-based-on-multiple-criteria-in-other-c) are some of those.

**MY BEST GUESS** - working from some of the lower-ranked answers to similar questions, I think that

```
SELECT t1.Col_2, t1.Col_4, COUNT(DISTINCT t1.Col_1) AS total 
FROM TABLE_1 t1 INNER JOIN Table_2 t2 ...
GROUP BY t1.Col_2, t1.Col_4
ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT t1.Col_1) DESC //not necessary but useful for trying to analzye the results
```

should give me what I'm looking for, but my uncertainty is high enough to justify putting it in the question instead of posting as a self-answer.

Comment: What's your DBMS? Does it support RANK?

Comment: DBMS - whatever command line operations timesten gives you by default. And yes, RANK is a supported operation. The database is Oracle timeten version 11.2.2.6.4

Comment: Your best guess is close, but you need  `COUNT(*)` instead of `COUNT(DISTINCT t1.Col_1)`, it will be faster and the the count might be wrong with DISTINCT. And in your SETUP query the DISTINCT is probably not needed, too, this will cause a huge overhead if the optimizer can't remove it.

Comment: "all other tables just have a foreign key off a column in Table_1." - it is not clear what You mean. Does Table_2 have primary key on COL_1 and Table_1 foreign key on COL_3 to primary key of Table_2?

Comment: Every other table has been normalized directly off of table_1. So, every table besides table_1 has a foreign key constraint to one of table_1's columns and no 'independent' primary key that's used. It's more of a semantic distinction than a directly encoded distinction, but I thought it would help people who might get side-tracked on the other tables.

Comment: I think there is some confusion of therms.

"A FOREIGN KEY in one table points to a PRIMARY KEY in another table."
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

Table_1 can have foreign key constraint pointing to primary key (or at least unique constraint) of Table_2, Table_3 and so on. Not the other way. If it were so, Col_2 and Col_4 columns of table_1 would both both have to be unique and Your problem would be trivial.